# WebView as responder

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, nsfontmanager, nscolorpanel

I would like to receive the [`changeFont:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/changeFont%3a) and [`changeColor:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColorPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/changeColor%3a) messages in a `WebView` subclass.

According to the documentation, these methods are sent by `NSFontManager` and `NSColorPanel` respectively to responders.

Yet, they never get called in my `WebView` subclass. Is this the expected behavior? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I set the delegate then I'm not using the responder chain, which is what I want to do. The changeFont document explicitly says that all responders should get it, not just the delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently because the `WebView` had editable content the events were being consumed by a child responder.

The workaround was to listen to `WebViewDidChangeNotification` when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think is occurring

NSFontManager apparently sends the messages along the responder chain and not to the delegate.

I would set my CustomWebViewController to be the delegate of the window.

Comment: I don't have access to the controller. Just the WebView.